# Windows: files locked by process

Tags: python, winapi

Is there another winapi call to detect which files are locked by a specific
process then using duplicatehandle and ntquerysysteminformation?

I'm using restart manager api to register the files I'm looking for but,
unfortunately, restart manager api only returns a list of processes but doesn't return a mapping which process holds which file(s).

Comment: you can open file with `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` access only and query `FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation` for file - you got list of process id which use this file

Comment: I want to mark this answer as accepted, but there is no check sign as stated in the help center.
 _To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in_.
And I already waited more than 48 hours.

Comment: here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507578/winapi-get-the-process-which-has-specific-handle-of-a-file almost the same question with real code