# Winapi: Get the process which has specific handle of a file

Tags: c, windows, winapi, cmd, cygwin

Currently I have a software which has a file filter driver, during installation of software the driver is started as service in this way:

```
CreateService(serviceManager, name, displayName,
                          SERVICE_START | DELETE | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | SERVICE_STOP,
                              SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER, SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE,
                                  path, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Where path is `C:\Program Files(x86)\TSU\driver\TSUfsd.sys`.

The problem I'm having is during uninstallation of the software. It gives me access denied when software tries to delete `TSUfsd.sys` file.

I've checked how the software deletes the driver, and turns out it deletes it with `DeleteService` function, and waits for service to change its state from `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` to `SERVICE_STOPPED` and if it doesn't happen after some time, it gets the service `PID` and kills it with `ProcessTerminate` and then tries to delete the file with `rmdir /S /Q C:\Program Files(x86)\TSU\`.

I've tried to find the process which could have had the handle of the file(with Process Explorer) but could not find any. Then I thought maybe the service is still alive so I typed `sc query TSUfsd` but the service was gone too.

I've also tried to change permissions and grant full permissions to my user but same error still occurred.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any other ways to check which process(or anything else) can have a hold of a file?
2. I've also noticed that, whenever I try to delete the file with Cygwin(`rm TSUfsd.sys`) it deletes the file without a problem. What is the difference between deleting file with cmd(`del /f <filename>`) and with cygwin?

Comment: There was a nice utility called [`hanlde.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) by Mark Russinovich. Except you want to do it yourself in code, then you can enumerate all processes and hen inspect their handles?

Comment: in windows 10 - system hold loaded drivers and not let delete it until driver will be unload

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this task, starting with Windows Vista special exist `FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation` [`FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff728840(v=vs.85).aspx).

So we need open file with `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` (this is possible even if somebody open file with 0 share mode. of if we have no access to file (by it *DACL*) but have read access to parent directory). and call [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567052(v=vs.85).aspx) with `FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation`. on return we got `FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION` structure (defined in `wdm.h`) where list of `ProcessId` which hold this file(open file handle or mapped section. say if this file is exe/dll - we got process ids where it loaded). good also with this print process name for every id:

```
volatile UCHAR guz = 0;

NTSTATUS PrintProcessesUsingFile(HANDLE hFile)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION, ProcessIdList[64]);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PFILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION ppiufi;
    };

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = NtQueryInformationFile(hFile, &iosb, ppiufi, cb, FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation)))
        {
            if (ppiufi->NumberOfProcessIdsInList)
            {
                PrintProcessesUsingFile(ppiufi);
            }
        }

        rcb = (ULONG)iosb.Information;

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS PrintProcessesUsingFile(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
{
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    HANDLE hFile;
    NTSTATUS status;
    if (0 <= (status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, poa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0)))
    {
        status = PrintProcessesUsingFile(hFile);
        NtClose(hFile);
    }

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS PrintProcessesUsingFile(PCWSTR FileName)
{
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    NTSTATUS status = RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus(FileName, &ObjectName, 0, 0);
    if (0 <= status)
    {
        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName };
        status = PrintProcessesUsingFile(&oa);
        RtlFreeUnicodeString(&ObjectName);
    }

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS PrintProcessesUsingFile(PFILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION ppiufi)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    ULONG cb = 0x8000;

    do 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (PVOID buf = new BYTE[cb])
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                union {
                    PVOID pv;
                    PBYTE pb;
                    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
                };

                pv = buf;
                ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

                do 
                {
                    pb += NextEntryOffset;

                    ULONG NumberOfProcessIdsInList = ppiufi->NumberOfProcessIdsInList;

                    PULONG_PTR ProcessIdList = ppiufi->ProcessIdList;
                    do 
                    {
                        if (*ProcessIdList++ == (ULONG_PTR)pspi->UniqueProcessId)
                        {
                            DbgPrint("%p %wZ\n", pspi->UniqueProcessId, &pspi->ImageName);
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (--NumberOfProcessIdsInList);

                } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);
            }

            delete [] buf;
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer :) Since Building your code gives me `error: #error Compiler version not supported by Windows DDK
 #error Compiler version not supported by Windows DDK
` and I can't really update my compiler since it installed on my university computers and updating it would need permission and lot of time. @A A suggested handle.exe to solve the issue, does your code do the same thing as handle.exe?

Comment: @user3503143 - yes. the same - `FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation` - what is your compiler version ? and you can simply copy-paste wdk definitions (`NtQueryInformationFile` ) to own src

Comment: `(GCC) 4.9.2` We are using Cygwin. I've tried `handle.exe` and it gives `No Matching Handle Found`. What else could be the cause of it? User profile and file itself are not corrupted.

Comment: @user3503143 you definitely can compile this code by copy/paste some definition. i simply paste own ready as is. however here mandatory only `NtQueryInformationFile`, `FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS` and `FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION`. for say open file you can use `CreateFileW`, convert process id to name you can not use.

Comment: @user3503143 - include wdm.h as is for user mode app (so with windows.h) is hard. need include it in namespace + several  tricks. not try include wdm.h to project. simply copy/paste FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS and FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION and NtQueryInformationFile. file open with CreateFileW(`FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` and `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`) - really task is absolute posible

Comment: I started to copy needed resources but it turned out to be lot. At the end I managed to install VS 2017, but have some problem here too `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus` this function is undentified and I could not even find the documentation of it.

Comment: @user3503143 - you really not need [RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntrtl_8h.html#a0eef2a39be3e732e674a8f38df3a05c1) - i use it for convert *DosFileName* to *NtFileName*, because i use *NtOpenFile*. however you can use *CreateFileW* in this case you not need this api. again - begin from `FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS` , `FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION` and `NtQueryInformationFile` - copy-paste only this 3 definitions and call `NtQueryInformationFile` with `FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation`. begin from this.

Comment: Sorry for late response we had some electricity problem. Here is what I got https://pastebin.com/xxnaySFm The only error I'm occuring in in the pastebin link at the bottom. I could not understand the why is it occuring, hope you can help.

Comment: @user3503143 - this already only compiler issue. interesting that *CL* compile this expression without problem. you can use `rcb = FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION, ProcessIdList) +
   ppiufi->NumberOfProcessIdsInList * RTL_FIELD_SIZE(FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION, ProcessIdList);` or this `rcb = FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION, ProcessIdList) +
   ppiufi->NumberOfProcessIdsInList * sizeof(ULONG_PTR);` - all 3 the same

Comment: @user3503143 also about *Nt* function declarations - all it must be declared in `extern "C" { .. }` block (if you use *c++*), all must have `NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS  WINAPI` - look for `NtQueryInformationFile` - it not have this in your code. and finally - add `ntdll.lib` to linker input

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) https://pastebin.com/TQeysi0B I've added logs and it returns `ppiufi->NumberOfProcessIdsInList -> 0` which means no process has this handle right?

Comment: @user3503143 - yes, if `ppiufi->NumberOfProcessIdsInList == 0` after success call to `NtQueryInformationFile` mean that system not hold this file

Comment: @user3503143 - test for example on *c:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll* for view result, than say on *c:\windows\system32\ole32.dll* and compare

Comment: @user3503143 - however - if you run on win10 and file (*TSUfsd.sys*) is driver which is currently loaded - system hold this file (unlike previous windows version it not let let delete running drivers, like all windows not let delete running exe files), but it not show it usage - *NumberOfProcessIdsInList* will be 0. if this is your case - you need first unload driver (before delete)

Comment: On `ntdll.dll` the process started and never returned. I tried it on some other file and it returned correctly. Thank you very very much, and one last question, where did you learn all this stuff? :)

Comment: @user3503143 - *On ntdll.dll the process started and never returned* - this must not be. sure that error in your code exist. you need run code under debugger for view exactly where error. why it *"never returned"*. research this just now - very important for you. *where did you learn all this stuff?* - if i have situation when something "not working" - i never drop this, but research (does not matter how many time it take) until not fix or understand why this must not work

Comment: I currently seek how to find which program is using the folders/files. I find handle.exe and filelocksmith.exe which can do it but very slow. I check the code and they are using interface NtQuerySystemInformation which may be slow to trace all handles. And I run your code and find it's perfect with PrintProcessesUsingFile(HANDLE hFile) to list processID quickly. but why does it call PrintProcessesUsingFile(ppiufi) which will call NtQuerySystemInformation? just to list process Name? any trick if i don't call that because i wanna only get processID @RbMm

Comment: @vincent of course if you need only pid without name, you not need this function

Comment: thanks. One more question is why use  stack = alloca(0)  and RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack) to calculate length, which is larger than needed. In this way, if I define rcb with FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_PROCESS_IDS_USING_FILE_INFORMATION, ProcessIdList[1]) instead of 64, it works well even there are 2 processID returned because cb is bigger than processIdList[1] thanks to RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack). But will happen an exception for stack area corrupted. it's so tricky.

Comment: @vincent - not `alloca(0)` - this always error due bug in compiler, but `alloca(v)` where `v` is actually 0 but defined as `volatile`. and exception was is you use [`/RTCs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks?view=msvc-170) - *Enables stack frame run-time error checking*. remove this option and error is gone. i allocated stack correct - exactly how many need

Comment: what's the purpose of alloca(v)? if I do like this, buf = alloca(rcb), NtQueryInformationFile(hFile, &iosb, ppiufi, rcb, ...) without using stack and cb. It works well. But i think u may have some reasons to do like that.

Comment: @vincent this code is designed for allocate buffer **unknown** size. if we know what need size at begin - we can just do `alloca(rcb)`. but if we dont know size and size can changed between calls to `NtQueryInformationFile` - i use this very general code. the `cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf, stack)` - is how many allocated at current time and if we need `rcb` which is larger - `cb < rcb` - we need more allocated `rcb-cb` size. if use `/RTCs` option - it after allocate stack - set magic in stack for check after. so this not designed for work whith cumulative alloca

Comment: @vincent - anyway - alll this not related to main question - about get ID. this is my coding style. if you not like or not understand it - you can use own code - in what problem ? you not must copy my code 1 to 1. you need only undertstand basic of solution

Comment: Thanks for details. yeah, I am trying to understand the background of this solution. @RbMm

Comment: @vincent - `stack = alloca(guz)` is end of allocated buffer (need exactly this but not `alloca(0)` ). 
buf - is begin of allocated buffer - returned by `alloca`
in this case `RtlPointerToOffset(buf, stack);` is size of currently allocated - i use `cb` for this
`rcb` - how many need for buffer
if we have allocated `cb < rcb` - need more alloc `rcb - cb`.
so i and do `buf = alloca(rcb - cb)`
and again calc size `cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf, stack)`

Comment: So alloca(guz) is the highest address which can be allocated in function stack, and when memory is not enough, it will allocate rcb-cb and buf will be the combination of these twice allocation. i am puzzled with: first one is if i define some variables between these twice allocate, will these variables break "buf"? the second is what the relation between rcb-cb and cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf, stack)? cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf, stack) returns at least 64 and bigger than rcb-cb. is there something like pages which at least allocated 64 and stepped by some size bytes?@RbMm

Comment: @vincent - *if i define some variables between these twice allocate, will these variables break "buf"* - of course not. nothing will be breaked. my code is correct.