# How do I get a list of programs which have a file opened?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a win32 api function which lists the programs that currently are accessing a file and locking it?

Comment: I know it's possible, but it might not be as simple as a single API call.

Comment: This looks to be it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/restartmanager/nf-restartmanager-rmgetlist

Comment: [`FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class) return this info. look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507578/winapi-get-the-process-which-has-specific-handle-of-a-file/47510579#47510579

Comment: But couldn't I simply run the restart manager manually, and add the files that may have a file opened and then run RmGetList()?

Comment: you not need any restart manager, also internal this anyway call `NtQueryInformationFile` with `FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation`. this is only way get this information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Winapi: Get the process which has specific handle of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507578/winapi-get-the-process-which-has-specific-handle-of-a-file)

Comment: *"But couldn't I simply run the restart manager manually, and add the files that may have a file opened and then run RmGetList()?"* - Yes, you can (see [How do I find out which process has a file open?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120217-00/?p=8283)).