# Call Windows Function in Python

Tags: python, pywin32

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN

How can I call the above kernel method in python? I found an example on another stackoverflow post: [Winapi: Get the process which has specific handle of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507578/winapi-get-the-process-which-has-specific-handle-of-a-file)

The answer on this other post is essentially what I want to do, but in python. The goal is to be able to get a list of processes which currently are accessing/locking a file. This NtQueryInformationFile method seems to be exactly what I want. I know this can be done with ctypes, but I am not familiar or comfortable enough with ctypes to do this myself. How can I do this?

Comment: You tagged `pywin32`. Have you used that?

Comment: Pywin32 does not have the capabilities implemented for this method as far as I can tell

Comment: [this article](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2013-11-28-a-python-interface-to-signalfd/) shows an example of calling a kernel function from Python

Answer (score 0):

If there's no available wrapper for the function, you'll need to call the function yourself using ctypes.
The dlls windows uses are exposed through `ctypes.windll`, with `cytpes.windll.ntdll` being the one that exposes the function you need.

To help python convert arguments, it's usually a good idea to specify the function's argument and return types, which can be done through the `argtypes` and `restype` attributes on the function object, like so:

```py
function = cytpes.windll.ntdll.NtQueryInformationFile
function.argtypes = [ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE, ...]
function.restype = ctypes.c_long
```

ctypes exposes the common window types in the `ctypes.wintypes` module, though for most structures like the `PIO_STATUS_BLOCK` in your function you'll need to [define the struct yourself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) and add it to the argument list to use it properly. In case it's optional a void pointer and passing it None will suffice.

Also, do mind that windows handles are not the file descriptors that python exposes, to convert to/from them you can use the `..._osfhandle` functions from the msvcrt module

Comment: Looks like it would also require me to run multiple other windows functions like NtOpenFile :(

Comment: Does the function need some special handle? if it's an ordinary windows handle then you should be able to use a python file and a handle from it's file descriptor that you can get with the fileno method

Comment: I am not sure. I've been just doing some research into ctypes.