# Stream file, file in use, FileSystemWatcher and question about threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, filestream, filesystemwatcher

I've been trying to create a script which takes the content of a text file which may look like this (1 line text in a `.txt.` file):

```
SomeData     SomeData     SomeData
```

and these files are dropped randomly into a folder. Sometimes in 10's, sometimes 1 at a time. The files are then moved from the folder using robocopy to another folder roughly every ten mins.

Anyway, I wanted to read each file's single line of text and insert into the database.

Works fine once or twice, but then I get file is in use error.

Tried switching from `File.ReadAllText(textFile)` to `FileStream` and still have the same problem.

Can anyone help?

Also, I'm a little worried about the number of threads this may use when dropped onto a server. I can see the threads in Visual Studio Code, but interested to know what I could do to improve my script and make it more efficient?

I am new to coding! This will be my first.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace IDGFileSystemWatcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "C:/Test/";
            MonitorDirectory(path);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
            fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
            fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            string txtContents;
            string dir = "C:/Test/";
            string textFile = dir + e.Name;
            //string text = File.ReadAllText(textFile);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(textFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            txtContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();

            string[] splitstring = txtContents.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                 
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString =
                        "Data Source=computername;" +
                        "Initial Catalog=contents;" +
                        "User id=userid;" + 
                        "Password=password;";
                    
            string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.MB1B (Field1, Field2, Field3, TStamp) VALUES (@Field1, @Field2, @Field3, @TStamp)";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field1", splitstring[0]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field2", splitstring[1]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field3", splitstring[2]);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TStamp", now);

                connection.Open();
                int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Check Error
                if (result < 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into database!");
                }

                // connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using both `File.ReadAllText(textFile)` and `FileStream`.

I have tried to check if the files are in use but I am just copying and pasting test /txt files from one folder to another sometimes in 10's and sometimes in singles. Or dropping 50 test text files into a folder.

I've tried waiting for usage to time out (so the file isn't in use) and I have tried adding a pause to the script.

Please note that nothing is being written back to the file, I am simply reading a file and entering three items from the single line of text in the file to the database.

Comment: Execute in a loop: catch the exception, wait for a while, try reading again.

Comment: You are missing a ton of `using`s. `fs` `sr` and `conenction` all need `using`. That's unlikely to fix your issue, but should be done anyway.

Comment: To start with: the only thing any of the FSW  event handlers should do (to avoid typical negative side effects) is queue a task and finish. From experience, if your files are not very small, a created event should be given some sensible offset before trying to do anything with that file.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies ! I have to admit Im still learning here, Im just learning about variable scopes as the code below gives me a context error :) Ill keep hacking away! and I have just added 'using' as well

string txtContents;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        txtContents = File.ReadAllText(textFile);
        break;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}

Comment: Well, the FileSystemWatcher has some very specific quirks that can give you some serious headaches. So better have its documentation in a bookmark :D

Comment: Thanks guys seriously you have helped me a lot. So I have this working now where it doesnt appear to error even if I copy over the files, delete the files or generally try to break it. Its behaving much more as expected and I cant thank you all enough. The only question I have is how to make sure the SQL question is optimised with using? Where should I put a using? Ive tried  using.connection.Open(); but I get an error. 

Should I go start another topic?

Comment: Different question, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cite [the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.oncreated?view=net-8.0):

> The OnCreated event is raised as soon as a file is created. If a file is being copied or transferred into a watched directory, the OnCreated event will be raised immediately, followed by one or more OnChanged events.

Simply put, `OnCreated` event does not guarantee that the file has been transferred completely, which is why you will receive the file-in-use exception. There are [APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507578/winapi-get-the-process-which-has-specific-handle-of-a-file/47510579#47510579) to help you to detect if files are in use, but the most convenient solution should be try reading multiple times:

```
string txtContents;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        txtContents = File.ReadAllText(textFile);
        break;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: ^^ but not in the event handler! It should finish execution as fast as possible.

Comment: This seems more likely than my answer... Although I'm not sure we should be teaching newbies that it's good to use exceptions to handle an expected control flow state

Comment: A better solution would be to wait for file events to quiet down. Exceptions can be *very* expensive, especially when copying lots of files.