# How to offload SQL code to another task / thread - FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I've been hacking at this problem since 2 months ago! Im tired, confused, burnt out and disillusioned !

I want the code below to read a file when its dropped into a folder. Sometimes 2 or three files can be dropped into the folder in rapid succession. This will happen all day. I expect a total of 250000 files a year to be dropped into the folder. I wish the contents of the file to be entered into a database. Each file contains one line of text. I  split the text into four parts and insert into the database.

An example of a txt file being sftp'ed into the folder looks like this (single line of text). this file could be called textfile324324.txt for example

131115         004108          60   000890012

Two problems I have are that when a file is dropped into the folder, sometimes the SFTP script drops the file into the folder its still writing the file as filesystemwatcher is reading it, so I end up with a TMP file in the folder and not a txt file.

Also in testing, if I manually drop 1000 files in the folder in one go (lets go mad!), only around 700 files are read (and contents entered into database with no issues) but then the remaining files are not read. I dont see any errors at this point. The script just stops bothering to read files. I wonder if this if buffer size?

So Ive tried and tried since Decemeber to optimise the code below, I have various versions of it, and each time I hit a brick wall.

Where am I going wrong? Please note that I am new to C# and I dont fully understand threading. If I do need to be threading and offloading tasks could someone point me in the right direction with an example script?

I appreciate any help anyone is willing to give! Ive posted here before but I absolutely need a bit of hand holding with this one. Perhaps someone has coded similar before?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace IDGFileSystemWatcher
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = "C:/Test/";
        MonitorDirectory(path);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
        fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string txtContents;
        string dir = "C:/Test/";
        string textFile = dir + e.Name;
        //string text = File.ReadAllText(textFile);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(textFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        txtContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();

        string[] splitstring = txtContents.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
             
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString =
                    "Data Source=computername;" +
                    "Initial Catalog=contents;" +
                    "User id=userid;" + 
                    "Password=password;";
                
        string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.database (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, TStamp) VALUES (@Field1, @Field2, @Field3, @Field4, @TStamp)";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field1", splitstring[0]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field2", splitstring[1]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field3", splitstring[2]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field4", splitstring[3]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TStamp", now);

            connection.Open();
            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Check Error
            if (result < 0) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into database!");
            }

            // connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I was expecting the script to throw an error for whatever reason it stops reading files.

Comment: 1. Filter by extension (=> ignore .TMP) 2. Detect new File => _Monitor_ that file's size for a while ... if it hasn't changed for X times you looked => next stage. 3. "Next stage" = A queue from which a (or more?) worker pulls files to read and insert into SQL.

Comment: ^^ That's basically a pipeline, where the initial stage (the eventhandlers of the FSW) do _nothing more_ than put the detected file/path onto a queue. Done. That's _all they do_. They _need_ to execute as quickly as possible. It is crutial that that thread does nothing else than handle the event queue. Don't have it do more - offload as much as you can, especially file and DB I/O.

Comment: Filter => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter?view=net-8.0

Comment: If I remember correctly, I used to actually monitor file size _and_ last write. Having both stable (depends on your specific writer, in this case an FTP, I guess?) for a while is a good indicator of finished transfer and the filesystem having updated file state.

Comment: In that context, you may want to look into [BlockingCollections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview) and [Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels)

Comment: Note: wrap `SqlConnection` in a `using` statement. It is necessary to return the connection to the pool as soon as possible.

Comment: _"The script just stops bothering to read files."_ - That happens if you have a buffer overflow. You will miss events. And that's the exact reason why you need to offload, offload, offload.

Comment: It seems that this code has not fixed your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721400/stream-file-file-in-use-filesystemwatcher-and-question-about-threads/77721551

Comment: Not just the SqlConnection, also the FileStream and StreamReader (which you probably don't really need) -- As mentioned, you need a worker method that gets the file as input, take care of potential exceptions when reading it (the file may not be completed yet) and generates the output. As mentioned, if possible, Channels are very good here -- Double the default buffer if the FSW

Comment: A rough estimation of a first POC would look like this if I'd do it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cemSTJ // Just add FSW and SQL ...

Comment: [This article](https://petermeinl.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/tamed-filesystemwatcher/) seem to go into some of the issues with FileSystemWatcher and their solutions. But I would really consider some way to mark files as processed, so that you are not entirely reliant on the FileSystemWatcher to keep track of what is new or not.

Comment: ^^ I'd actually move processed files out of the watched folder.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replied over the weekend. 
@Fildor I cant move watched files out of the folder due to other systems in place.
Im going to try your filter by extension as that makes some sense to me. During testing Ive been cutting and pasting, dropping txt files into a folder. In production the folder is populated by SFTP service.

Comment: Shingo, it did fix to a point! The code I have posted above is one of about 4 versions, one of which (thanks Alexander!) is the using statement. Also using read-alltext r stream, and a few other lines of code here or there :) jonas Thanks for the article!

Comment: Chaps, Thanks for your help, I did get this working.

Comment: The solution was to monitor the onchange event rather than the created event. Once the TMP file was changed to a TXT File the script will read it. I can post my script here if it helps other users.

At the same time, Im now having problems with garbage collection so I may need to make another post for this if I cant work it out in the coming days.